# do join tables need to use conventional naming in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

say I have `company` and `employee` tables, does my join table have to be called `companies_employees`? I don't see anything about this on the rails documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name of join table can be changed. Here is document of [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).

> If the default name of the join table, based on lexical ordering, is
>   not what you want, you can use the :join_table option to override the
>   default.

So, you can change it like this:

```
# Company model
has_and_belongs_to_many :employees, join_table: "comp_emps"

# Employee model
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, join_table: "comp_emps"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact none of the tables have to be named a particular way -- that's just convention. You can override the table name for any model, but usually you would do because you have a legacy schema.

And similarly, if you have a model that belongs to both Company and Employee it doesn't have to be named `CompanyEmployee` (conventional table name would be `company_employees`) or `EmployeeCompany` (conventional table name `employee_companies`, but it often makes sense to.